# How do I replace characters not in range [0x5E10, 0x7F35] with '*' in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, hex

I'm not familiar with the how regular expressions treat hexadecimal, anyone knows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
$str = "some മനുഷ്യന്റെ";

echo preg_replace('/[\x{00ff}-\x{ffff}]/u', '*', $str);
// some **********

echo preg_replace('/[^\x{00ff}-\x{ffff}]/u', '*', $str);
// *****മനുഷ്യന്റെ
```

The important thing is the `u`-modifier (see [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

> This modifier turns on additional
>   functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Pattern
>   strings are treated as UTF-8. This
>   modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0
>   or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3
>   on win32. UTF-8 validity of the
>   pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

And [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) a short description why `\uFFFF` is not working in PHP:

> Perl and PCRE do not support the
>   \uFFFF syntax. They use \x{FFFF}
>   instead. You can omit leading zeros in
>   the hexadecimal number between the
>   curly braces. Since \x by itself is
>   not a valid regex token, \x{1234} can
>   never be confused to match \x 1234
>   times. It always matches the Unicode
>   code point U+1234. \x{1234}{5678} will
>   try to match code point U+1234 exactly
>   5678 times.

Comment: Does the `\uXXXX` syntax work with `u` modifier? Can you check if this works? `/[\u00FF-\uFFFF]/u`

Comment: @openid: You have one `[` to much.