# remove utf-8 figure spaces with php

Tags: php, utf-8, string

I have some xml files with figure spaces in it, I need to remove those with php.
The utf-8 code for these is e2 80 a9. If I'm not mistaken php does not seem to like 6 byte utf-8 chars, so far at least I'm unable to find a way to delete the figure spaces with functions like preg_replace.

Anybody any tips or even better a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `preg_replace('/\x{2007}/u', '', $stringWithFigureSpaces);`?

`U+2007` is the unicode codepoint for the [*FIGURE SPACE*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm).

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728070/how-do-i-replace-characters-not-in-range-0x5e10-0x7f35-with-in-php/2728372#2728372) on a similar unicode-regex topic with PHP which includes information about the `\x{FFFF}`-syntax.

Regarding you comment about the non-working - the following works perfectly on my machine:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $str = "a\xe2\x80\x87b";  // \xe2\x80\x87 is the FIGURE SPACE
php > echo preg_replace('/\x{2007}/u', '_', $str); // \x{2007} is the PCRE unicode codepoint notation for the U+2007 codepoint
a_b
```

What's you PHP version? Are you sure the character is a *FIGURE SPACE* at all? Can you run the following snippet on your string?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    printf('%x ', ord($str[$i]));
}
```

On my test string this outputs

```
61 e2 80 87 62
a  |U+2007|  b
```

---

**EDIT** after OP comment:

`\xe2\x80\xa9` is a [*PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) which is unicode codepoint `U+2029`, so your code should be `preg_replace('/\x{2029}/u', '', $stringWithUglyCharacter);`

Comment: Yeah I did, it did nothing :(

Comment: I guess it's something else then, it took me some time to get the right characters pasted (the orig file is rather large) but it clearly prints: e2 80 a9 and not: e2 80 87

Comment: Somehow I got stuff confused, been strugling with this for a while now. Sorry about that, thanks you very much for your assistence!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe mb_convert_encoding function can help.