# unicode preg_replace problem in php

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8, preg-replace

I've got the string

```
$result = "bei einer Temperatur, die etwa 20 bis 60°C unterhalb des Schmelzpunktes der kristallinen Modifikation"
```

which comes straight from a MySQL table. The table, and the php headers are both set to UTF-8

I want to strip the 'degree' symbol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol and replace it with the word 'degrees' to get:

"bei einer Temperatur, die etwa 20 bis 60degreesC unterhalb des Schmelzpunktes der kristallinen Modifikation"

but I can't get it to work with preg_replace.

If I do:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\xB0/u'," degrees ", $result ); - I get an empty string
```

And if I do::

```
$result = preg_replace('/\u00B0/u'," degrees ", $result ); - I get the error:
```

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 1 in /var/www/html/includes/classes/redeyeTable.inc.php on line 75

I'm not great with encodings... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first solution you post works perfectly for me.

Comment: According to this page (and to your error message BTW), you cannot use \u http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php

Comment: Are you sure you have the same symbol? Unicode has many similar characters.

Comment: The first one should work fine.

But if you are just replacing that, you can use the faster str_replace() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I agree the first option should work. I have no idea why it strips ALL text out. I'm finding PHP and UTF-8 to be a rather tricky combination. I'm just using a standard ubuntu 10.04 install and the latest stable PHP build, don't know why character handling fails at every turn.

Answer (score 30):

Use

```
$result = preg_replace('/\x{00B0}/u'," degrees ", $result );
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728070/how-do-i-replace-characters-not-in-range-0x5e10-0x7f35-with-in-php/2728372#2728372) for more information on the `\x{FFFF}`-syntax.

It's important to note the difference between `\xB0` and `\x{00B0}`:

- `\xB0` denotes a single character with hex-code `B0` (`176` decimal) which is the degree symbol (`°`) in ISO-8859-1 for example
- `\x{00B0}` denotes the unicode codepoint `U+00B0` which describes the degree symbol (`°`) in the unicode system. This codepoint will be encoded using two bytes `\xC2\xB0` when using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That works! Thank you Stefan and everyone who contributed.

My mistake was not using the { } around the unicode codepoint. I appreciate the difference between \xB0 and \x{00B0} - it was more desperate trial and error that had me settling for \xB0 replacement on a unicode string.

Stackoverflow once again is a life saver!

Comment: @Ed: You could mark the answer as "accepted" to show other users that this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't know how many hours I spent searching for why my regex to replace some UTF8 chars was not working, and thanks to this trick with \xNN vs \x{NN}, I finally got it right. Many thanks Stefan :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you use the 'u' modifier, the pattern is supposed to be treated as utf-8, so why not simply write '°' instead of '\u00B0' or '\xB0'?

Comment: $result = preg_replace('/°/u'," degrees ", $result );  

does work.... why doesn't it work giving the string in hex?