# preg_replace in smarty for removing unicode symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, smarty

I am using

```
{'/[\x2700-\xFFFF]/u'|preg_replace:'':'✅این یک تست است✅'}
```

to remove ✅ from the unicode text, but it does nothing.

Unicode hex for ✅ is 2705

**EDIT**: if i use `{'/✅/u'|preg_replace:'':'✅این یک تست است✅'}`

It returns correct string `این یک تست است`....strange!

Comment: I think it should be `'/[\x{2700}-\x{FFFF}]/u'`

Comment: To strip off one single codepoint you don't need a range.

Comment: @revo, it is an example, but actually it is a range.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks but no, it does not work

Comment: And `{'✅این یک تست است✅'|regex_replace:'/[\x{2700}-\x{FFFF}]/u':''}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It returns null.

Comment: I tested `regex_replace` already but nothing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually it should be `\x2700` not `\x{2700}`

Comment: @Amir In PHP regex, Unicode code points should be written with `\x{XXXX}` syntax, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3141168/3832970).

Comment: Really, i don't understand the reason for down vote.. is this a very simple question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, syntax does not work in smarty i mean

Comment: It must be due to `{` and `}`. Try `{'✅این یک تست است✅'|regex_replace:'/[\x{{2700}}-\x{{FFFF}}]/u':''}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It returns `}-\x}]/u':''}`