# php preg_replace iOS apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, windows

How do I replace the iOS apostrophe ’ with php using **preg_replace** ?

I tried

```
preg_replace("/(\u2019)/", '-', $mytring); //Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u

preg_replace("/(’)/", '-', $mytring); //Not working
```

Based on answer, I tried

```
preg_replace("/(\x{2019})/u", '-', 'it’s'); //it’s
```

But I'm on Windows, does it matter?

**Edit:** OK it works now, I had to html_entity_decode it first and I couldn't see it from the dump. Thanks to people who answered.

Comment: *Not working* isn't helpful at all. Please provide a live demo. With PCRE it is `\x{XXXX}` not `\uXXXX`.

Comment: Try `\x{2019}` instead of `\u2019`

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large

Comment: Enable `u` flag.

Comment: It works see here https://3v4l.org/lu2lj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch *Unicode* using `\x{xx}` and use the [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (**PCRE_UTF8**) when you need a character value length of 4:

```
preg_replace('/\x{2019}/u', "'", $mytring);
```

Comment: @Eric I'm on Windows too, and your edit shows the same regex as before, is it normal ?

Comment: please refresh... also what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Eric yes you used the `/u` modifier but did not catch unicode using `\x{2019}`. PHP 7.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\x{2019}/u',"-", $mytring);
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140734/unicode-preg-replace-problem-in-php)