# need PHP function correction to make slug with bangla (ex. কিন্তু-মৈত্রী-কালো-এলাচ)

Tags: php, slug

Slug function is working perfectly in English but when I try to put Bangla it showing only ---

### now showing:

input title: Top চাঁ mom কিন্তু মৈত্রী (কালো এলাচ)

output slug: top---mom----------

### Need to show this way

input title: Top চাঁ mom কিন্তু মৈত্রী (কালো এলাচ)

output slug: Top-চাঁ-mom-কিন্তু-মৈত্রী-কালো-এলাচ

---

here below is my php function of slug in my blog.... how to fix this ???

```
function slug($text){ 
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');
  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);
  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
  if (empty($text))
  {
    return 'n-a';
  }
  return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package for bangla slug for php laravel site [Sohibd Bangla slug](https://packagist.org/packages/sohibd/laravelslug)

Answer (score -1):

use `mb_strtolower()` to for the lower case of the string.
And for `preg_replace`, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728070/how-do-i-replace-characters-not-in-range-0x5e10-0x7f35-with-in-php/2728372#2728372).

Hope, it will work.

Comment: It will not work directly. use these resources and do as you need. I'm not going to share direct code! lol.

Comment: really lol..... if i can fix with try I did not ask for help.... u my country boy really funny...